# Value based Page split in a SSRS Report with Multiple Tablixes

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, msbi

I have a `SSRS Report` which have multiple `tablixes` as shown below

[image]
This report is having `multi-value parameters`.  the output of this `report` is shown as below

[image]

Now I need to do a page `split` on this report based column value `loan_id`. Records with `Loan_ID` 1 come in the first page, Records with `loan_id` 2 come in 2nd page of the report...etc. As below

expected output :

[image]

To do this,  I have added a `Rowgroup` on both `tablixes` with value `loan_id`.  Then In `pagesplit` properties of group I ticked `'split using each instance of group'`

But when the `Report` runs I didn't get the desired result. i got output as below

First page of the report

[image: First page of the report]

Tablix 1 data ends here and Tablix 2 begins in 4 th page

[image: 4th page of the report ( Tablix 1 data ends here and Tablix 2 begins)]

I figured out the issue because `ssrs` processing first `tablix` entirely  then start with next `tablix`. But I need both of the tablixes processing at the same time.

Pls help...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `PageBreak` to occur based on an expression. In your row group properties set the `BreakLocation` to `End`. Set the `Disabled` property to an expression like this:

```
    =IIf(Fields!loan_id.Value = Previous(Fields!loan_id.Value), True, False)
```

In other words, you will get a page break each time an loan ID is different than the previous one.

Comment: thanks steven. But I am confused to choose the disabled property. For which tablix i need to apply this and what will be the option for another tablix

Comment: @bmsqldev This property is on your **row group**. You only need 1 tablix.